# CoAP Example for android Use Californium

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, coap

I'm trying to build a CoAP server in android, and i's using californium's example.

https://github.com/curioustechizen/Californium/tree/4ace5b85974a0646aaaa6ab43c9314d1c5a438e1

But I got error with `Http.java` in package `ch.ethz.inf.vs.californium.layers`

it shows

```
The type org.apache.http.entity.ContentType  cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I'm thinking the problem is about the wrong .jar file
the library I imported is like this:

> apache-mimne4j.core-0.7.2.jar californium-0.18.7-final.jar
>   commons-codec-1.6.jar commons-io-2.4.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>   google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar
>   gson-2.1.jar guava-11.0.1.jar httpclient-4.2.1.jar
>   httpclient-4.3.2.jar httpcore-nio-4.2.1.jar jsr305-1.3.9.jar
>   junit-3.8.1.jar junit-4.8.1.jar mockito-core-1.8.5.jar

---

hope anyone can tell me whats the problem or how to fix it, and also ask to some open source about CoAP's android example.

Comment: You can try nCoap. For reference please have a look of https://github.com/okleine/spitfirefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a http-components jar there.
Do you use maven?

Please note: your fork is too old (2 years).
You can find the actual Californium version at https://eclipse.org/californium/
It does not have android support but I see your fork only removes a lot of files and adds an android manifest at most - so it could be done too.

Comment: i didnt use maven cause still learning Java, i go to check the needed library and go to download it from google.